# How to code like this kind of output?When I click a specific link it will show some form(not sure if it is form)

Tags: php, html, jquery

How to code this? when I hover my name It pop outs like a form but I think its not a form

[image]

I want exactly the same like this because I want to happen in my page when I hover my name it has a value of id and send it via ajax to the php then the php script queries the id and return its other details then the other details will display like in the image I already have a function and a php code the only I need is how to do like this image

code for js function:

```
function searchWarriors() {
var id = $("#name").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "retrieve_result.php",
    type:"GET",
    datatype:"json",
    data: {id: id},
    success: function(data) {
        var toAppend = '';
        if(typeof data === "object"){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                var warrior = data[i];
                toAppend += '<ul class="ul">';
                toAppend += '<li>'+data[i]['loc']+'</li>';
                toAppend += '<li>'+data[i]['email']+'</li>';
                toAppend += '<li>'+data[i]['sex']+'</li>';
                toAppend += '</ul>';
            }
            $(".ul").remove();
            $("#details").append(toAppend);
        }
    }
});
return false;
```

}

Code for my PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

include 'functions/class.php';

$db = new DB();

$result = $db->getDetails($_GET['id']);

$details = array();

foreach($result as $values){
    $details[] = $names;
}
echo json_encode($details);
?>
```

Code for my html to call function

```
    <?php
foreach($result as $id){
//I don't know if this is right
echo'<a id="name" href="myphpcode.php"?id='.$id['user_id'].'>'.$id['name'].'</a>';
}
?>
<div id="details">

</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It sounds as though you're already able to fetch the user's details into a JSON object via ajax, but just want to render it like in the image? If so, you'd be better off just returning HTML from your ajax call and appending this into the relevant element. So for example, if you visited the URL you're calling, `retrieve_result.php?id=1`, you'd see the content exactly as you wish it to appear in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to normally create exactly how you want the pop-up to look in a php script, then  use jQuery and call the script with $("#Popup-id").load(script-url.php?getvar=1). The div element will need a high z-index in order to show on top of the screen.